# How to avoid calling `useState` in a map method?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a snippet within a React component similar to this:

```js
<div>
  {items.map((item) => {
    const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false)

    return (
      // ...     
    )
  })}
</div>
```

I am calling `useState` in a map method, but I read in the documentation that hooks must be top level. I am wondering how could I refactor this code to avoid doing it?

Comment: state belongs to an instance of a component. If you need this state for every item the component renders individually, you need to keep an object in the state where every item has a key and the corresponding value in that object.

Comment: Move the `isExpanded` state to the body of the function component and convert it to hold the value for each element of `items` you are mapping. Or abstract whatever it is that you are mapping into a React component so the hook usage is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### option 1

In your case i would suggest creating a new component for the item.

```
<div>
  { items.map((item) => <Item key={} />) }
</div>

...
const Item = () => {
    const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false)

    return (
      // ...     
    )}
}
```

#### option 2

```
const [expandedIds, setExpandedIds] = useState([])
...
<div>
  {items.map((item) => {
    const expanded = checkIsExpended(item)
    return (
      // ...    
    )
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: Would this solve the problem? I would still need to be mapping `<Item/>` components.

Comment: @ytrewq Yes, but every `Item` component would have the call to `useState` unconditionally at the top. So it would solve the problem but the state would be local to the item. If you need it in the parent you would have to go with an object that stores the expanded state for each individual item.

Comment: @trixn It's ok to have local state in this case. Thank you!

Comment: @ytrewq sorry, i correct the code and provide another solution.